# Alternative language for pattern-matching

Tags: python, programming-languages, wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching

I'm writing a program in *Mathematica* that relies on pattern-matching to perform payroll and warrant of payment verification. The crux of the problem is to compare different data files (both CSV and XLS) to make sure they contain the exact same information, since pay is handled by two different third-parties.

My use of *Mathematica* makes development of the program quite streamlined and fun, but is prohibitive on a distribution level. CDF format is not an option, since the program requires the user to import data files, something which WRI does not permit in CDF.

An ideal programming language for this task would enable me to pack it up as standalone, for OS X, Linux or Windows, as well as being able to do the pattern-matching. Support for GUI (primitive or extensive) is also needed.

I thought of Python to translate my program in, but I'm not sure if it's a good bet.

What suggestions do you have?

---

My only understanding of pattern-matching is [that](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html) which the *Mathematica* [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PatternMatchingFunctions.html) has taught me.

An example of a task that *Mathematica* handles perfectly is the following:

Import XLS file, sort data by dates and names, extract certain dates and names. Import CSV file, sort data by dates and names, extract certain dates and names.

Compare both, produce a nice formatted output containing desired (missing) information.

Navigating through the data in *Mathematica* is also pretty easy and intuitive.

Comment: If by pattern matching you mean regular expressions, Perl was dessigned with regex in mind

Comment: Prolog, Erlang have very powerful pattern matching in them and they are platform independent. Also a lot of companies use Prolog for the exact problem you are describing, it is very exact as it proves the solution along the way.

Comment: Be more specific. What kind of "pattern matching"?

Comment: Python has `re`, a regular expression library, and `tkinter`, a graphical user interface library. What type of pattern matching are you looking for?

Comment: You don't really build a standalone program with Prolog, although you can, you write your prolog to match the cases that you need to then you can call it from various other languages, mainly C from what I have used. So, you would run the matching from prolog in C and if it matches then you can proceed in the C program.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower My question is edited accordingly. I don't think regex would be _ideal_ for the job, as I've already tried it before in Mathematica and it was rather slow - but it could work.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm pretty sure they qualify as answers, though. Then I can vote and ask questions in the comments.

Comment: @sean could you explain (or direct me to information that does) what you mean by *it proves the solution along the way*?  That's new to me.

Comment: Prolog is a logic programming language, in that you provide it facts to prove a problem.  When you program in Prolog you are actually building up a table of facts wherein each statement tries to match.  It does this by substituting facts with subfacts until it reaches a base case.  When it has reached the base case it has proved that the input matches something in the table. It can be thought of as a programmable database.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) which seems to have all the features you want and is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a more standard language that has some capabilities for working with spreadsheets, unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I would suggest using just simple Java with the Apache POI library, specifically made for horrible spreadsheet formats. Also it's considerably faster to pick up than Haskell is, though I suppose if you already know Mathematica it wouldn't be that bad to move over to another mathematically inclined language.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is a logical programming language in that it actually does a proof based on the facts that you give it.  Thus is you provide it with the approiate facts for warrenty or payroll information it will be able to prove that it is either of them by trying to get to a base case in which both sides of an equation cancel.  There is more to this but I'm on my phone at the moment.

For your situation you would be able to read data in a easier to program language and verify you parameters in Prolog and as long as your Prolog facts are correct it will be able to quickly verify that your data is valid.  It can be thought of as regular expressions on steroids with a lot more functionality.

http://www.amzi.com/articles/lsapi_design.htm